# push from ftp server

Tags: git, github

Hi I am developing a site on my ftp server and am wondering if I can push commits directly from it. what would be the process for this using git. my server is on shared hosting using dreamhost.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am developing a site on my ftp server" ?

Comment: Are you doing the development on a machine which happens to also be an FTP server?  If so, then you can push commits like any other host.  Are you developing locally and storing on an FTP server?  If so, why?  If GitHub is your source control, just push to there.  Sticking an FTP server in the middle is sort of a hacky workaround for source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have (or can obtain) ssh access, you can push from your server.

Comment: do i just type     ssh username@mywebsite.com in git bash to connect

Comment: i think i figured it out, i connected now am following this,  http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/